# Why doesn't my JQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine in Python. My login page has the following code:

```
       <script>    
            function gSignIn(googleUser) {
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); 
                console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
                $('.notlog').hide();
                $('.log').show();
                $('#uName').text('Welcome, ' + profile.getName());
            }

            function nusSignIn(user){
                $('.notlog').hide();
                $('.log').show();
                $('#uName').text('Welcome, ' + user);
            }
        </script>
```

When i login with google:

```
       <div class="g-signin2 notlog" data-onsuccess="gSignIn"></div>
```

the gSignIn function works fine and those elements with notlog class disappear. But when i do this for openID:

```
       {% if user_mail %}
                    <span id="nusname" style="display:none">{{user_mail}}</span>
                    <script> 
                        var name = document.getElementById("nusname").innerHTML;
                        alert(name);
                        nusSignIn(name);
                    </script>
                    <a href="{{nuslogout}}" class="log">
                        Logout
                    </a>
       {% else %}
                    <form action="/nusopenid" method="post">
                        <button>Login with Nus OpenID</button>
                    </form> 
       {% endif %}
```

only the login with Nus OpenID disappears and nusSignIn function doesnt appear to work, but the alert(name) does and the logout hyperlink appears as well.

user_mail is passed from the python of the application.

Comment: any errors on teh developer console?

Comment: there's no errors when i upload it

Comment: sorry, I was talking about the browser developer console where developers look to see if there are any errors when running their code

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit dumb but how do i check

Comment: F12 key. This opens up the developers tools. You just can't develop anything in JS without these tools and especially the console, that will give you all errors and help you debug your app.